# how to apply redux developer tools with reduxThunk

Tags: redux, redux-thunk, redux-devtools, redux-devtools-extension

**here is my code**

```
import React        from "react";
import ReactDOM     from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import "normalize.css/normalize.css"
import  "./styles/styles.scss";
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import reduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';

import AppRouter from './routers/AppRouter';
import reducers from './reducers';
import {AUTH_USER} from "./actions/types";

//
const createStoreWithMiddleware =  applyMiddleware(reduxThunk)(createStore);
const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers);


const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
if(token){
    store.dispatch({type:AUTH_USER});
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <AppRouter />
    </Provider>
    , document.getElementById('app'));
```

so i want to [Use redux-devtools-extension package from npm](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension#13-use-redux-devtools-extension-package-from-npm)

**how can i implement with createStoreWithMiddleware**

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Simply wrap the middleware with `composeWithDevTools`.Like at first import :

```
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
```

Add all your middleware in an array.For now there is only one.

```
const middleware = [
    reduxThunk,
];
```

Then instead of `createStoreWithMiddleWare` do

```
const store = createStore(reducers, composeWithDevTools(
  applyMiddleware(...middleware),
  // other store enhancers if any
));
```

So the code becomes:

```
import React        from "react";
import ReactDOM     from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import "normalize.css/normalize.css"
import  "./styles/styles.scss";
import { Router, Route, IndexRoute, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import reduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';

import AppRouter from './routers/AppRouter';
import reducers from './reducers';
import {AUTH_USER} from "./actions/types";


const middleware = [
    reduxThunk,
];

const store = createStore(reducers, composeWithDevTools(
applyMiddleware(...middleware),
// other store enhancers if any
));


const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
if(token){
    store.dispatch({type:AUTH_USER});
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <AppRouter />
    </Provider>
    , document.getElementById('app'));
```

Haven't tested but should work.